# What is it that keeps Windows 10 v1903 from letting an old AMD driver display videos?

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading from v1803 to v1903 there is an issue with the AMD Radeon video driver. When playing videos there is only audio but no video. Embedded browser videos work but poorly. With the driver disabled the videos are playing correctly (in VGA resolution).

However, in v1803 the same driver worked just fine.

I have no idea what would keep Windows 10 v1903 from letting this driver display videos. It’s not like the driver was rejected. It was installed by Windows Update itself and the device is working “properly”.

It seems I am not the only one who has this kind of problem but I could not find any proposed solution (like installing the original* driver) that worked for me. I have still hope that somebody eventually finds the magic switch otherwise I will be stuck with v1803 forever.

*There will be no AMD update to this driver since the device (HD4250) has already legacy status.

Comment: Eventually older hardware and drivers get left behind, can you upgrade the graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post
[ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250 and Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/ati-mobility-radeon-hd-4250-and-windows-10/e922ad81-4c92-4065-88cb-c88a6e75119e?tab=AllReplies#tabs),
dating from 2017, has this helpful answer:

> The 4250 doesn't have win 10 drivers so you have to use MS drivers. I found this that might work - http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/acer/laptops-desktops/aspire-7551/750

That answer was verified as working by the poster, but the drivers listed
are pretty old, so I do not believe that they will work, although you may
of course try them out.

The same website has newer drivers available at the webpage
[ATI Radeon HD 4250](https://www.driverscape.com/download/ati-radeon-hd-4250),
although still dating from before Windows 10 1903.

You will find pretty recent drivers on
[DriverPack AMD ATI Radeon HD 4250 drivers for Windows 10 x64](https://drp.su/en/devices/video/amd/ati-radeon-hd-4250?os=windows-10-x64).

If you get into trouble because of the installation of these drivers,
boot into Safe mode under VGA to uninstall them.
I suggest before starting to create first a System Restore point, just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! But that was not my question: What keeps W10 1903 from displaying the video content when it worked fine in 1803 using exactly the same driver?

Comment: evidently the diver is no longer supported in 1903, this happens all the time when OS's move forward.

Comment: In v1903 some changes were made to the driver model. Several drivers stopped working, not only yours, and some companies were very quick to release new drivers for v1903. Unfortunately, no new drivers are created for older hardware like yours, so you have to try drivers for similar but newer hardware that are still updated. If you have another GPU in the computer, you could disable the 4250 in Windows (better not do it in the BIOS, if at all possible).

Comment: Of course but in this case it might be something different since MS provided the driver with the upgrade. Why would they do that if the driver was not compatible? Also, all the other graphics functions work. I still believe it might just be a setting.

Comment: Microsoft's testing is not that comprehensive, seeing the number of problems that their updates cause on various hardware platforms, up to and including bricking some computers. I don't believe they will make an effort to test obsolete hardware, if they even have your model in their lab, especially now that there were news articles about cuts in that department. I think I have found all the drivers that could potentially work for you, but of course there is no guarantee.

Comment: Now something strange happened: I went back to v1803 using an image I had previously made. Guess what, I can no longer play videos with this version too although it worked when I created the image.

Comment: Maybe the problem is unrelated to the upgrade. Try to install a codec pack such as [K-Lite](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Comment: As for 1803, I installed a codec pack and re-installed the AMD driver in save mode and it worked.  Next try will be the same with 1903 ...